# Can't print a long long double output

Tags: c, printf, double

My question is simple, How to print a long long double output?. I know how to print a long double i.e

```
printf("%Lf",output);
```

Comment: How would you **declare** a "long long" double? Have you tried it? AFAIK, no such type exists...

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I'm not aware of any that supports `long long double`.

Comment: I'm using gcc compiler

Comment: As others have said, `long long double` does not exist. If it is `long long int` you can use the format specifier `%lli`. Or, `%llu` for unsigned.

Comment: I think you may be confusing data types; the decimal data types supported by C/C++ are single precision (float) and double precision(double). Anything else is non standard and may be compiler/architecture specific. But, personally, I've never heard of "long long double"

Comment: Do you have code that declares a `long long double` that compiles?  If so, we'd like to see it, along with the compilation command you used and the compiler version.

Comment: My gcc says `error: 'long long double' is invalid long long double lld;`, what about yours?

Comment: @Pandrei: Err... `long double` does exist, and *is* covered by the standard ("extended precision if supported by the implementation", otherwise equivalent to `double`). It's `long long double` that's non-existent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by `long long double`?  Does your compiler really accept this syntax?  There seems to have been a bug in old versions of `gcc` that used to parse this `long long double` and recognize it as `long long int`. This bug has been fixed a long time ago: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6634

As you are aware, the C Standard supports long long integer types:

- `long long int` can be printed with format `%lld` or `%lli`,
- `unsigned long long int` with format `%llu`, `%llo` or `%llx`,

And a long floating point type:

- `long double` printed with `%Lf`, `%Lg` or `%Le`.

Other types may exist on some implementations for specific targets, but are non standard:

- `__float128` or `binary128`, also known as quadruple precision, documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format
- `__float256` or `binary256`, also known as octuple precision, documented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format

Neither of these are implemented as `long long double` on common compilers...

These formats are not widely supported, to say the least, and no standard `printf` conversion is defined.  Look at your compiler documentation for a possible extension or a specific function to convert these extended precision floating point formats, if they are at all available on your target.

Answer (score 2):

There are `long long`, `long long int` and `long double` (depend on compiler).

There is **no** `long long double`. Not ever.

Comment: `long long unsigned`. ;-)

Comment: IEEE 754 well defined [binary256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format) for over 8 years.  Should C adopted it, calling it "long long double" is quite reasonable. AFAIK, @david watson could have a trivial error or is working on leading edge compilers.  This answers "Not ever." is an overstatement.